# Simmer delayed_release_selected error no resource selected

Tags: r, simulation

I'm quite a long way through this simulation. I'm creating a dedicated resource and a pooled resource and this particular trajectory can access both.
The issue starts if I then want to use delayed_release_selected to then create some cool down space after dropping the customer for the server. If I just release the customer the below code works fine. Here is a reprex of the error.

```
arrive <- c(1:5) 

traj <- trajectory("traj") %>%
simmer::select(resource = c("dedicated_resource","pooled_resource"), policy = "first-available") %>%
seize_selected(amount = 1) %>%
timeout(1) %>%
delayed_release_selected(task = 1)

plot(traj)

sim <- simmer("sim") %>%
add_generator("cust",traj, at(arrive), mon = 2) %>%
add_resource("dedicated_resource", 2) %>%
add_resource("pooled_resource", 2)

sim %>%
run(until = 800)
```

This is throwing this error...
Error: 'cust0' at 2.00 in [Timeout]->SetCapacity->[Synchronize]:

no resource selected

There doesn't seem to be any examples floating about. I've tried pulling apart the function itself but I just cannot get this to work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh additionally delayed_release works fine as well. Just seems to be when you add the selected bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised as a bug to Devs. Will update here as well if I hear back.
[Link](https://github.com/r-simmer/simmer.bricks/issues/18)